# What is the best practice for routing relationships in a REST api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, attributerouting

Lets say I have two objects, Users and Appointments, where Users may have one or many appointments.

I am curious if I should allow consumers of the API to 'filter' by users from the Appointments controller.  Here are the calls I have in mind for the GET operations:

```
Users Controller
GET
api/Users
api/Users/{userId}
api/Users/{userId}/Appointments
api/Users/{userId}/Appointments/{appointmentId}

Appointments Controller
GET
api/Appointments/
api/Appointments/{appointmentId}
```

I am curious if it is a good idea  (good practice) to implement filters for the users on the Appointments controllers... So the calls above would become:

```
Appointments Controller
GET
api/Appointments/{userId:int?}
api/Appointments/{appointmentId}
```

In the above calls I've added an optional querystring parameter for the userId that will default to null.  This would allow a caller to either GET all appointments, or to get appointments by userId.

I guess I am not really certain what is considered a best practice for objects with relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want simplicity I would suggest

Users
GET

```
api/users
api/user/{id}
api/user/{id}/appointments
```

Appointments
GET

```
api/appointments
api/appointment/{id}
```

And from the looks of it `api/Appointments/{userId:int?}` doesn't read well since a user has appointments and an appointment only has a single user. In the case of the endpoint `api/Appointments/{appointmentId}` I'm not sure what `AppointmentId` is but if it's an **int** you'll have to do some funky stuff to look up an appointment or a user based on an **int**, in which case the ID's could be the same.

Getting too far into the depth of an object tree can get confusing as far as url structure.